# Accepting Multiple Values In Checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do i store multiple values from a checkbox form to the database? I have scoured through various threads and still have not come up with anything. Mainly because the "problems" always seem to involve different parts.

For the sake of clarity here's an example to mimic what i am trying to do and im not sure which part of it is wrong.

So say we have this table created for our Person

```
#schema.rb
create_table "persons", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string  "hobby", default: [], array: true
end
```

And in the model

```
#person.rb
serialize :hobby
```

So if say i had a form with checkboxes to let the user pick his favourite hobbies. And for example because this list of hobbies is really long, i stored the values in a module.

```
#app/models/concerns/hobby_data.rb
module HobbyData
  Activities = [
    item_one,
    item_two,
    ...
  ]
end
```

In the controller, im permitting an array

```
params.require(:person).permit({:hobby => []})
```

And in my form

```
#form for new/edit person

<% form_for @person do |f| %>
#other fields
<% HobbyData::Activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= check_box_tag("hobby[]", activity) %>
  <%= activity %> #for the activity name
<% end %>
```

I can now see the values being passed in from the logs

`hobby => ["item_one", "item_two"]`

But its not hitting the database, any idea why?

Comment: why don't you store the hobbies separately instead of as an array ? Would it make more sense to have Person.hobbies return the person's hobbies ? Especially when you work with a check box. It means you already have predefined hobbies.

Comment: i didn't quite consider that because the only reason i'm taking this approach instead of using a `text_field` for users to just type whatever it is they want in is to restrict them to a selection of choices. didnt think that creating a Hobby class and creating the whole bunch of hobbies and use active record association would "make sense". would using activerecord associations be better?

Comment: Since you are working with check boxes as you mentioned I thought you had a list of hobbies. How about just let them type their hobbies into a box and store it all as a string instead of an array ? Or do you want to create links for the hobbies ?

Comment: I dont need links for hobbies of any sort, just need to display them. The reason why i would like a checkbox because i would like to filter the users by their hobbies, typing it in would possibly create variations which would impair the filter function. But im not quite sure if creating a `Hobby` class and creating 20-30 acitvities to use activerecord associations would make sense.

Comment: How about letting users create the hobbies ? You could have something like first or create for hobbies. Each time a user adds a hobby, it searches in your hobby table if it already exists else it creates it. Each hobby has many users and each user has many hobbies. Hobbies would have to be unique. How does that sound ? You wouldn't have to create a list yourself and later you could display potential hobbies by pulling them from the DB.

Comment: i did consider that but the main idea being taking away "control" from the users, preventing all sorts of funky variations etc. which is why i chose this approach

Comment: It is kind of hard to have both things. On one side you want the user to input their hobbies on the other side you want to control the variations. I think the first_or_create approach would work the best but you could make it a little more complicated using RegEx and try match hobbies by common words. Football and American Football would match for example under football. Just suggesting things.

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't seem that complex to me? I am just pre-defining a list of words for the users to choose from to pass in as a string. Doesn't seem like something very difficult to do?

Comment: Sure, if you have a list of hobbies it is really simple and you can just create that list really quick. In your form you can than iterate over all your hobbies and create a check box for each hobby which they can mark. I mean the Regular Expression part as being more complex way of handling it.

Comment: I've actually edited my question to show what i have done. Do you mind taking a look to see why is it not hitting the database?

Comment: @angkiki +1 for giving detailed context/code around the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in your form. Since you are using `check_box_tag`, you must explicitly declare the scope where the `hobby[]` attribute belongs to. So your form should be like this:

```
<% form_for @person do |f| %>
  <% HobbyData::Activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= check_box_tag("person[hobby][]", activity) %> <-- notice this change
    <%= activity %> #for the activity name
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

On another note, there's also a form helper for this so you can do it like this...

```
<% form_for @person do |f| %>
  <% HobbyData::Activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= f.check_box :hobby, { multiple: true }, activity, nil %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

More here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

Comment: Same issue, where i can see it being passed as an array, but its not saving to the database... no rollback errors as well. Any idea the possible cause?

Comment: Sorry, worked like a charm. Error was on my part parsing the params. Cheers mate :)

Answer (score -1):

From the **[official rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)**

```
 fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}, &block)
```

> Creates a scope around a specific model object like form_for, but
>   doesn’t create the form tags themselves. This makes fields_for
>   suitable for specifying additional model objects in the same form.

Comment: I appreciate that you are attempting to help me, but that in itself doesn't quite explain the solution to my problem...